Clone Trooper Face model
I've seen a lot of very accurate clone trooper face model photos online recently, like the one by High Ground Animations. Does anyone know where they got the model for the face, or did they sculpt it themselves?

The Blender StackExchange is for usage questions, so it's not the place to ask for help with finding third-party resources. Try the Blender group on X, the Blender Artists Forum, or a search engine.
